# rotation and containment api

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have two view controller, A and B. A is meant to support only Portrait when instead B can support landscape. I'm displaying B using the containment api.

```
 [self addChildViewController:child];
[self.view addSubview:child.view];
child.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[child didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I've implemented

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    UIViewController *current = _presentingChild ? _child : self;
    return [current shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    UIViewController *current = _presentingChild ? _child : self;
    return [current supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
```

everything works like a charm. If the devices is landscape while presenting A and I present B the rotation immediately turn.

the problem comes when I dismiss B. If the device is landscape A is shown landscape (and this should not happen).

Do you have suggestion how to face this problem? I know I can use a modal controller and that would solve the problem. But I don't want to use a modal vc for this specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods are inside the A viewcontroller, that contains the B viewcontroller.

If I am right, the way you have implemented the two methods is bad: when the current view controller is self (if _presentingChild condition is false), you should have an infinite recursion because, for example, shouldAutorotate will be called recursively without ending (you are returning `[self shouldAutorotate]`).

So, if you are not experiencing infinite recursion, there are only two possibilities:

- the two methods are never called
- the _presentingChild condition is always true

Check and let me know